# Complex nested json file to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I need to convert this complex json file into a specific dataframe. In particular, I just want to focus on certain keys that are present in the various dictionaries. I have tried various solutions but have not managed to isolate what I am interested in. Here is the json file in the meantime:

```
{
      "user_data": {
        "tester_name": "JOHN DOE",
        "tester_mail": "john.doe@gmail.com",
        "role": "manager",
        "seat": "New York"
      },
      "votes": [
        {
          "query": "marketing",
          "results": [
            {
              "lead_author": "name surname",
              "total_score": 37.64869086098502,
              "expert_skills": "marketing, Photoshop, ecc.",
              "id": "01022020",
              "articles": [
                {
                  "title": "first title",
                  "link": "https....",
                  "authors": "authors of first article",
                  "abstract": "first abstract",
                  "score": 14.982715947149883
                },
                {
                  "title": "second title",
                  "link": "https....",
                  "authors": "authors second article",
                  "abstract": "second article",
                  "score": 14.64152669579352
                },
                {
                  "title": "third title",
                  "link": "https...",
                  "authors": "authors third article",
                  "abstract": "third abstract",
                  "score": 8.02444821804162
                }
              ],
              "vote": 5
            },
            {
              "second_lead_author": "name surname",
              "total_score": 29.6242426429434,
              "expert_skills": "automotive",
              "id": "83838484",
              "articles": [
                {
                  "title": "first title",
                  "link": "https...",
                  "authors": "authors first article",
                  "abstract": "first title",
                  "score": 14.982715947149883
                },
                {
                  "title": "second title",
                  "link": "https...",
                  "authors": "authors second article",
                  "abstract": "second abstract",
                  "score": 14.64152669579352
                }
              ],
              "vote": 0
            },
            {
              "third_lead_author": "name surname",
              "total_score": 29.6242426429434,
              "expert_skills": "database",
              "id": "237374457",
              "articles": [
                {
                  "title": "first title",
                  "link": "https...",
                  "authors": "authors first title",
                  "abstract": "first abstract",
                  "score": 14.982715947149883
                },
                {
                  "title": "second title",
                  "link": "https:....",
                  "authors": "authors second article",
                  "abstract": "second abstract",
                  "score": 14.64152669579352
                }
              ],
              "vote": 0
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

The result I expect to achieve is this:

```
tester_name     query             vote    vote    vote
John Doe          marketing        5        0       0
```

What i've tried so far:

```
data = json.load(open('file.json'))
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df
```

I tried using json_normalize but this is the output I can get:

```
votes
[{'query': 'marketing', 'results': [{'lead_author': ...         

user_data.name  user_data.mail          user_data.role    user_data.seat
John Doe        john.doe@gmail.com          manager           New York
```

Thank you in advance for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the string (`s`) in your question, you can get the data you want with

```
>>> import json
>>> j = json.loads(s)
>>> j['user_data']['tester_name']
'JOHN DOE'
>>> j['votes'][0]['query']
'marketing'
>>> [thing['vote'] for thing in j['votes'][0]['results']]
[5, 0, 0]
>>>
```

Parse the json first to extract your information and collect it as a list of *rows*, or a dict of columns then feed it to the [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#dataframe) constructor. Although a dict of columns or list of dicts might need extra work as there are multiple columns with the same name in your desired result.

---

```
d = {}
d['tester_name'] = j['user_data']['tester_name']
d['query'] = j['votes'][0]['query']
for i,result in enumerate(j['votes'][0]['results']):
    d[f'vote{i}'] = result['vote']
print(d)

>>>
{'tester_name': 'JOHN DOE', 'query': 'marketing', 'vote0': 5, 'vote1': 0, 'vote2': 0}
```

---